# VBA Tying Up in a Do While Loop

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I'm using Excel 2010.  I have a Do While loop processing a large table over 100,000 rows long. If it finds a particular cell in the table, it inserts two rows after that cell and copies the contents of that row to the two new blank rows just created. The loop works fine until it gets to about the 20,000 row and then it locks up.  Up to that point it is processing perfectly.  It does not always lock up on the same row. I'm using a copy, then a paste special to duplicate the row.  After the copy paste is done for the row, I clear the clip board with "Application.CutCopyMode = False". If I comment out the copy/paste, the loop successfully completes.
 For the amount of data that I'm working with, I would guess that it will insert about 30,000 rows based on the original table. Is there anything odd about copy/paste special that I should know about?

Comment: Can you post your code? Is the row counter variable an integer or a Long. If you have used integer, change it to Long.

Comment: The counter is Long.  That was my first concern too.  If that were the issue, it would tie up on the same row with each run. I'm thinking some cache is filling up in Excel and causing the lock up.  I'm going to try the suggestion on the following suggestion to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a table, why do you need to insert rows?

Append them on the end of the table. If the order is an issue a table in a particular order can be put in that order with a sort (a sort key which is probably implicit in your table already).

Better yet - append the new rows to an in memory table object and paste the entire table object to the end of the original table when your loop is complete. This way you also avoid processing your inserted rows, get much simpler logic in the loop, and the process will probably run faster.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the table ends up feeding a limit in an sql query.  I wanted to insert the new rows following the original to preserve the order.  I'll try appending to the end to see if it works better.

Comment: I changed the paste to the rows to the bottom of the table.  Ah, it looked so promising. It locked up at around the 24,000 row after adding about 7k rows to the bottom.  I failed to mention before that the the lock up does not occur at the same point each time the program runs.  I usually locks up anywhere between row 19,000 and 25,000. Has anyone seen a VBA copy/pastespecial problem with big files?

Comment: My next attempt will be to read the row into an array and then write the array out to the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 0):

First, I commented out the pastes and it failed. The insert of the two rows also failed without the copy and the pastes.  My solution was to first order the starting table. As I found a row that needed duplication, I read that row into an Array and then saved the array to the row past the bottom of the table.  After processing the table, I then reordered the rows using the order column I first created and then deleted that column.  Runs faster then the copy/paste but I lost the cell formatting in the new rows.